# Any SQLite profilers available?

Tags: sqlite, profiler

Are there any good SQLite profilers? I need something similar to what [JetProfiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) offers for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite includes an experimental [Tracing And Profiling C API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html).

Comment: Not really what I am looking for... I am not that interested in details about what happens while executing a single statement, what I need is a tool that just looks which statements take long and runs EXPLAIN on them.

Comment: The callback function registered by sqlite3_profile() is invoked as each SQL statement finishes. The profile callback contains the original statement text and an estimate of wall-clock time of how long that statement took to run.