# How to measure the time that a piece of code takes to execute?

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling, time-measurement

Suppose I want to measure the time that a certain piece of code takes. For that I would normally do something like this

```
clock_t startTime = clock();
//do stuff
//do stuff
//do stuff
//do stuff
float secsElapsed = (float)(clock() - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

What if the program is multithreaded and context switches occur within the part which I want to measure? How would I measure the time that my code takes to execute excluding time spent on other threads? Even if there are tools that do it, I would very much like to know *how* they're doing it.

Comment: do you want wall clock time ? Or actual time spent on the cpu by that one thread ? Note that both are quite different - even for single-threaded applications.

Comment: You could see if your platform supports `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` - this in theory (I've not tested it myself) should report the time specific to that thread.

Comment: @Sander: Time spent on the cpu by that thread, I suppose

Comment: @Armen, so dark ages.. ;) Why don't you use `QueryPerformanceCounter`? AFAIK, you have to pin the thread to a specific CPU to get best results though (`SetThreadAffinityMask`) - not sure how the windows scheduler works, but on linux you can control which cores the scheduler uses and which it can't so you can guarantee that the core you're using will not be used by the scheduler (and therefore your thread interrupted)...

Comment: Parhaps [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32) may help. `GetThreadTimes` API funciton may come handy, unless you're measuring CPU cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to measure how long code takes to execute.

If you are interested in the *relative* performance of certain functions, a [profiler](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) is the only way to go. Note that this will de-emphasise the impact of blocking I/O due to the computation overheads it induces.

If you want the [clock-based *time*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) of certain functions, there are loads of options.

Personally I would say [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) is sufficient.

If you want to get *precise*, use [RDTSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter)

If you want to get *really* precise, you'll want something like this

```
t1 = rdtsc();
t2 = rdtsc();
my_code();
t3 = rdtsc();
my_code_time = (t3-t2) - (t2-t1)
```

You will need to repeat this block to account for thread scheduling discrepencies, and also pay attention to cacheing effects.

Answer (score 2):

This is why code benchmarking basically sucks- because you *can't* know how long it takes. Things like being pre-empted by the OS are unpredictable at best. Use a professional profiler, as they may have code in them that can deal with these problems, or don't bother. Writing `clock()` style things is utterly meaningless.

Comment: You can (on Linux at least) mark the thread as real-time. Further to that you can use cpu affinity and segregate off a core just for your test. Usually you don't need this absolute guarantee for profiling, but in some cases it can help.

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux terminal use 'time path_to_app'

This will return everything you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared two very simple classes. The first one ProfileHelper the class populate the start time in the constructor and the end time in the destructor. The second class ProfileHelperStatistic is a container with extra statistical capability (a std::multimap + few methods to return average, standard deviation and other funny stuff).

I have used this idea often for profiling. I guess you could make it work even in a multi-thread environment. It will require a bit of work, but I don't think it will be so difficult.

Have a look at this question for more information [C++ Benchmark tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362978/c-benchmark-tool/5423391#5423391).