# measure time for popcount function in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit, cpu-speed

i  am interested how to put it in  loop so that get real time which is taken by cpu to execute each different operation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
const uint64 m1=0x5555555555555555;
const uint64 m2=0x3333333333333333;
const uint64 m4=0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
const uint64 m8=0x00ff00ff00ff00ff;
const uint64 m16=0x0000ffff0000ffff;
const uint64 m32=0x00000000ffffffff;
const uint64 hff=0xffffffffffffffff;
const uint64 h01=0x0101010101010101;

uint64 popcount_1(uint64 x)
{
    x=(x&m1)+((x>>1)&m1);
    x=(x&m2)+((x>>2)&m2);
    x=(x&m4)+((x>>4)&m4);
    x=(x&m8)+((x>>8)&m8);
    x=(x&m16)+((x>>16)&m16);
    x=(x&m32)+((x>>32)&m32);
    return (uint64)x;
}

//This uses fewer arithmetic operations than any other known
//implementation on machines with slow multiplication.
//It uses 17 arithmetic operations.
int popcount_2(uint64 x)
{
    x-=(x>>1)&m1;//put count of each 2 bits into those 2 bits
    x=(x&m2)+((x>>2)&m2);//put count of each 4 bits into those 4 bits
    x=(x+(x>>4))&m4; //put count of each 8 bits into those 8 bits
    x+=x>>8;//put count of each 16 bits into their lowest 8 bits
    x+=x>>16;
    x+=x>>32;
    return x&0x7f;
}
////This uses fewer arithmetic operations than any other known
//implementation on machines with fast multiplication.
//It uses 12 arithmetic operations, one of which is a multiply.
int popcount_3(uint64 x)
{
    x-=(x>>1)&m1;
    x=(x&m2)+((x>>2)&m2);
    x=(x+(x>>4))&m4;
    return (x*h01)>>56;
}
uint64 popcount_4(uint64 x)
{
    uint64  count;
    for(count=0; x; count++)
    {
        x&=x-1;
    }
    return count;
}
uint64 random()
{
    uint64 r30=RAND_MAX*rand()+rand();
    uint64 s30=RAND_MAX*rand()+rand();
    uint64  t4=rand()&0xf;
    uint64 res=(r30<<34 )+(s30<<4)+t4;
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int testnum;
    while (true)
    {
        cout<<"enter number of test "<<endl;
        cin>>testnum;
        uint64 x= random();
        switch(testnum)
        {
            case 1: {
                    clock_t start=clock();
                    popcount_1(x);
                    clock_t end=clock();
                    cout<<"execution time of first method"<<start-end<<" "<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 2: {
                    clock_t start=clock();
                    popcount_2(x);
                    clock_t end=clock();
                    cout<<"execution time of first method"<<start-end<<" "<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3: {
                    clock_t start=clock();
                    popcount_3(x);
                    clock_t end=clock();
                    cout<<"execution time of first method"<<start-end<<" "<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 4: {
                    clock_t start=clock();
                    popcount_4(x);
                    clock_t end=clock();
                    cout<<"execution time of first method"<<start-end<<" "<<endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"it is not correct number "<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it writes on terminal always zero inspite of which number test i enter,it is clear for me why because 10 or even 20 and 100 operation is not  anything for modern computer,but how could i dot such that get  if not exact answer,approximation  at least?thanks a lot

Comment: what a handsome mess, that was

Comment: Related, but not quite a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497630/how-to-measure-the-time-that-a-piece-of-code-takes-to-execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just repeat all the tests a large number of times.

The following repeats <strike>1 Mio (1024*1024)</strike>2^25 times for each test. You might want to divide the times to get the time in nanoseconds, but for comparison the total numbers would be fine (and easier to read).

```
int main()
{
    int testnum;
    while (true)
    {
        cout<<"enter number of test "<<endl;
        cin>>testnum;
        uint64 x= random();

        clock_t start=clock();
        switch(testnum)
        {
            case 1: for(unsigned long it=0; it<=(1ul<<26); ++it) popcount_1(x); break;
            case 2: for(unsigned long it=0; it<=(1ul<<26); ++it) popcount_2(x); break;
            case 3: for(unsigned long it=0; it<=(1ul<<26); ++it) popcount_3(x); break;
            case 4: for(unsigned long it=0; it<=(1ul<<26); ++it) popcount_4(x); break;
            default:
                cout<<"it is not correct number "<<endl;
                break;
        }
        clock_t end=clock();
        cout<<"execution time of method " << testnum << ": " << (end-start) <<" "<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note also fixed** `start-end` to `(end-start)` :)

Comment: also did a callback-style version here: http://ideone.com/8uU01 (I'd prefer that; note that IdeOne has lowres clocks (and no optimization enabled, apparently)

Answer (score 3):

You want to perform a microbenchmark of a very cheap operation.  You need to:

- **Make a loop** around the cheap operations; one that takes long enough to time reasonably; e.g. around a second.
- Ensure that you **use the result from one loop iteration in the next** to avoid the compiler just omitting the body entirely.
- Wrap the entire loop in a function, **mark the function as not-inlinable** with a compiler-specific attribute (again, to ensure the compiler doesn't just omit the call) and call *this* function from your timing function.  **Alternatively**, return a value depending on all loop iterations *and actually use that return value* (e.g. print it or store it in a `volatile` variable) in your main program to ensure the compiler can't just optimize the program and remove it.
- Additionally, you should **use high-resolution timers** and not `clock()`.  On windows this would be `QueryPerformanceCounter(&tick_count)`, on unix `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec_var)`, and on macos have a look at `mach_absolute_time()`.  Another advantage of (some of) these methods is that they measure CPU time, not wall-clock time, and are thus slightly less variable in the face of other activity on the system.

Again, it's **absolutely critical** to make sure you actually *use* the values computed either by storing them in a `volatile` variable, printing them or by returning them from a non-inlined function to ensure the compiler can't just optimize them away.  And you do *not* want to mark your core method non-inlinable, since function call overhead may well swamp such microbenchmarks; for similar reasons you should probably avoid `random`.  This is why you should benchmark a function containing a loop calling the (inlinable) function you're actually interested in.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;

inline uint64 popcount_1(uint64 x)// etc...

template<typename TF>
uint64 bench_intfunc_helper(TF functor, size_t runs){//benchmark this
    uint64 retval = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<runs; ++i) retval += functor(i); 
    // note that i may not have a representative distribution like this
    return retval;//depends on all loop iterations!
}
template<typename TF>
double bench_intfunc(TF functor, size_t runs){
    clock_t start=clock();//hi-res timers would be better
    volatile auto force_evalution = bench_intfunc_helper(functor,runs);
    clock_t end=clock();
    return (end-start)/1000.0;
}
#define BENCH(f) do {std::cout<<"Elapsed time for "<< RUNS <<" runs of " #f \
    ": " << bench_intfunc([](uint64 x) {return f(x);},RUNS) <<"s\n"; } while(0)

int main() {
    BENCH(popcount_1);
    BENCH(popcount_2);
    BENCH(popcount_3);
    BENCH(popcount_4);
    return 0;
}
```

Simply omitting `volatile`, for example, causes GCC 4.6.3 and MSC 10.0 on my machine to report 0s spent.  I'm using a lambda since function pointers aren't inlined by these  compilers but lambda's are.

On my machine the output of this benchmark on GCC is:

```
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_1: 3.7s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_2: 3.822s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_3: 4.091s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_4: 23.821s
```

and on MSC:

```
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_1: 7.508s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_2: 5.864s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_3: 3.705s
Elapsed time for 1073741824 runs of popcount_4: 19.353s
```